# Single Resistor on Common Cathode Display Is Not Limiting Current (With 1 segment lit)

Tags: arduino, current-limiting

Today I did a little test and hooked up my arduino nano to a seven segment common cathode display.

I attached a single 1k resistor to the cathode pin of the display, and then lit a single segment with the 5V pin of the arduino nano. I probed the resistor leads with a multimeter to check the current.

Turns out this did not limit the current at all. Why could that be?

Update: Well I now notice that probing the resistor seems to be causing a short, because the current SHOOTS up like a mother* whenever I probe it. How should I go about measuring the current?

Comment: What current did it show?

Comment: Where did you connect the probes?

Comment: Lets put it this way, the current was unlimited because it fried one of the LED's.I am probing the cathode resistor, and that seems to be what causes the short.

Comment: What did you measure and how to come up this conclusion? Did you really use multimeter in current measure mode over the resistor?

Comment: That doesn't mean it was unlimited - just not limited enough.

Comment: Yes I did measure the current in current mode over the resistor. Is that a boo boo? And the current shot up to 80mA. I unplugged it quickly.

Comment: The easy way is to measure *voltage* across the resistor, then use Ohms Law to calculate the current. That way you don't need to insert the meter in series to measure current directly.

Comment: When you've finished with the multimeter, make sure the leads are plugged into the voltage-measuring terminals, not the current-measuring terminals. That way, a little absent-mindedness next time you use it won't result in something broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you used the multimeter in current measure mode, and measured over the resistor, that is wrong. You short circuited or bypassed the resistor with multimeter so it prevented the resistor ti limit the current, and too much current passed via the LED and multimeter. Correct way to measure is the multimeter in voltage mode and measure voltage over the resistor. Or current mode when multimeter is in series with the resistor.

Answer (score 4):

To measure the current in your case, you need to put the multimeter **in series** with the resistor (in general, you put the multimeter in series with the current flow you want to measure).

When used in current measurement mode, the multimeter is effectively a very low resistance (internally, it uses a "[current shunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunt_(electrical)#Use_in_current_measuring)" between its measurement terminals, which can actually just be a piece of thick wire (!) and then measures the voltage drop across the low resistance of the current shunt, to calculate and display the current flowing through it).

[This page](https://www.homofaciens.de/technics-metrology-current-voltage_en.htm) shows the internals of a DMM - notice the thick wire I've marked with a red ring; that is the current shunt for a (probably large) current measurement range e.g. 10 A

[image: Current shunt inside digital multimeter]

<sub>Image source: Figure 3 from [Digital Multimeter](https://www.homofaciens.de/technics-metrology-current-voltage_en.htm), with current shunt (left side) marked in red</sub>

So if you use a multimeter (set to current measurement mode) to measure "across an LED's series resistor" then you are shorting out that resistor, which increases the LED current as there is no longer a voltage drop across that resistor - as you saw.